# Android / Java странный метод

Tags: java, android

Взял метод, который был у меня в прошлом проекте:

```
private boolean inCircle(Coin coin, int tx, int ty){
    int u1 = (tx-coin.getX())*(tx-coin.getX()) + (ty-coin.getY())*(ty-coin.getY());
    int u2 = Setting.coinRadius * Setting.coinRadius;
    if (u2 >= u1) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Почему он всегда возвращает false, даже когда последнее условие выполняется?

---

[image: proof]
Даже в таком состоянии переходит к строчке return false;

Comment: Значит, не выполняется.

Comment: Либо `false` возвращается при другом вызове метода (и, соответственно, при других значениях `u2` и `u1`), либо вы некорректно проверяете результат вызова метода.

Comment: Здесь будет true. Поставте фигурные скобки и убедитесь в этом. в 100й раз убеждаюсь что отсутствие скобок порождает проблемы.

Comment: @Eugene Troyanskii, к сожалению, наличие скобок проблему не решило

Comment: Хочу отметить, что данная ситуация решается через return u1 <= u2;  
Но меня интересует корень этой проблемы.

Comment: @Jorik пока вы не сможете предоставить воспроизводимый пример, вам помочь не смогут. [Вот пример](https://goo.gl/RGHw91) того, что для `u1=1105` и `u2=6561` метод возвращает `true`.

Comment: В таких случая , на всякий, делают clean - rebuild  проекта.